# Biblatex: maxcitenames is set to 2 but more names are shown in the citation

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

I have trouble in citing an article with `biblatex`. The option `maxcitename = 2` is used, however more than two names are shown in the citation.

Here is how I have set up my `biblatex`:

```
\usepackage[
            backend=biber,
            style=ext-authoryear,
            sorting=nyt,
            uniquename=init,
            giveninits=true,
            maxcitenames=2,
            maxbibnames=99,
            dashed=false,
            isbn=true,
            doi=true,
            url=false,
            articlein=false,
            ]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{family-given}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

And the article I am trying to cite is the following:

```
@article{Nie2007,
author = {Nie, Xu and Chen, Weinong W. and Sun, Xin and Templeton, Douglas W.},
doi = {10.1111/j.1551-2916.2007.01819.x},
journal = {Journal of the American Ceramic Society},
number = {8},
pages = {2556--2562},
title = {{Dynamic Failure of Borosilicate Glass Under Compression/Shear Loading Experiments}},
volume = {90},
year = {2007}
}
```

Using `\cite{Nie2007}` I expect an output like ***Nie et al., 2007*** but the actual output is ***Nie, W. W. Chen, Sun, et al., 2007***. Any suggestions on how to solve the issue with showing to many names in the citation?

Comment: Typically that happens because there is another entry with the first author and biblatex tries to make the list unique. Check `uniquelist` in the documentation for the various options here.

Comment: Indeed with only this reference in the document the output is _Nie et al._ as expected.

Comment: Using `uniquelist=false` solved the problem. Thanks @UlrikeFischer! :-)